# Do enemy blockades and Mystery Box Challenges need to be finished with all 5 characters to get each character's stamp?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

Do you need to clear the Mystery Box challenges and enemy blockades with all 5 characters as well to unlock the 5 "beaten every course with this character" stamp?

Answer (score 1):

Answer according to GameFAQs: yes.

"In order to get the last five character stamps, you have to beat all the levels with every character. This includes Blockades and Mystery Houses but does not include Captain Toad levels. In multiplayer, the character has to touch the flag for it to count. After gaining access to World Crown, you will be able to see what characters you have beaten a level with with the other collectibles."

http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii-u/718915-super-mario-3d-world/cheats